# Trouble destructor,call python's object with pointer in boost.python

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

when I call python's function with pointer as an argument in boost.python, there are some troubles in destructor.
The following is a sample code

c++

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace boost::python;

class A {
public:
    A() {
        std::cout<< "A start"<<std::endl;
    }
    ~A() {std::cout<< "A end" <<std::endl;}
}
class B {
public:
    B() { aa=new A; }
    ~B() { delete aa; }
    void run(object ct) {
        _obj=ct();              //creat a python object
        _obj.attr("fun1")(aa);  //call a function named "fun1" with a pointer arg
        _obj.attr("fun2")(aa);  //call a function named "fun2" with a pointer arg 
    }
    A *aa;
    object _obj;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(ctopy)
{
    class_<A> ("A",init<>())
    ;
    class_<b> ("B",init<>())
    .def("run",&B::run)
    ;
}
```

python:

```
import ctopy
class tc:
    def fun1(self,tt):
        print "fun1"
    def fun2(self,tt):
        print "fun2"
bb=ctopy.D()
bb.run(tc)
```

this result:

```
A start
fun1
A end
fun2
A end
A end
```

## note:

The "A end" has been printed three.I try it in "valgrind"，there are some errors.I just want to run the destructor once.How to do?

Comment: @JesseGood,Not the same.This is a problems come from boost.python library rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand what's really happening, you're missing a copy-constructor:

```
B()
  A()
B::run()
  A(a)     <- copy construct A to pass by value
    fun1() <- arg passed by value
  ~A()     <- delete copy
  A(a)     <- copy construct A to pass by value
    fun2() <- arg passed by value
  ~A()     <- delete copy
~B()
  ~A()
```

In your example, `aa` is passed by value, that's where the copies come from. It does not matter if `aa` is a pointer or not, boost will convert it to an object that is passed to your python methods.

If you want to avoid additional copies of `A` you can pass `aa` *by reference* rather than *by value*:

```
_obj.attr("fun1")(boost::ref(aa));
_obj.attr("fun2")(boost::ref(aa));
```

Which will result in:

```
B()
  A()    <- constructed once
B::run()
  fun1() <- arg passed by reference
  fun2() <- arg passed by reference
~B()
  ~A()   <- destroyed once
```

See [Calling Python Functions and Methods](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/python/doc/v2/callbacks.html#argument_handling) for more info.